# CodeIgniter not calling a js file

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter I've got a view file setup in the root folder, then I've got some Javascript files in a js folder as a sub-folder in the view. I tried doing simply:

```
<script src="js/jquery-blink.js" language="javscript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. So is there a specific inclusion technique I need to be performing in order to include my external view requirement files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the URL-helper you can insert a dynamic base URL which you set in the `application/config/config.php:`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/'; // example
```

Now, whenever you call the `base_url();` function, CodeIgniter will replace it with the set base URL:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-blink.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This line will then become:

```
<script src="http://localhost/ci/js/jquery-blink.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Remember that you need to load the helper like this `$this->load->helper('url');` or add it in the 'helpers' array in `application/config/autoload.php`

Comment: `<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/jquery-blink.js" language="javscript" type="text/javascript"></script>` Your methodology doesn't seem to work. But to add application/views/ after echoing out the base_url() inside the view seems to work just fine. Is this good practice though?

Comment: If I was you I would separate CSS and Javascript from your view folder. I like to keep a public folder **outside** the CodeIgniter folder, so that `public/` will be relative to the index.php file. That's why I used that example. After all, when fetching resources you are not referencing the views, you are references the controller (which calls the views).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a call to the absolute path:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-blink.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When going to a controller other than the default one, the browser think you are inside a subfolder.

If you go to http://ecample.org/index.php/controller/ then with your current script link, your browser will think you are looking the JS file in /controller/js/jquery-blink.js

But adding the slash infront of the src path, makes it look in the absolute path.

Comment: Because you taught me something. That counts doesn't it? Lol

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby, you should only mark this as answer if it SOLVES your problem, otherwise other people will find this question and be confused why its the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Set base url in the your config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your website url here'
```

Add base tag in your html head.

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />

<script src="js/jquery-blink.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If still not working check your .htaccess file